# my form is not responmsive on ipad mini 4 view

Tags: javascript, html, css

[website screen shot on ipad mini4 view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMPrY.jpg)

my form is not responsive on this view. i have added all the view port and i also have set my body size to 100%.

LOOK UP PROPERTIES
                     The most complete source of properties for buying or renting

                    
                      
                      
                      
                         
                       

                        To Rent
                        For Sale -->

                    
                        For Sale
                        
                        
                        
                     


                    
                         To Rent

```
</form>
```

Comment: share css/hml code

Comment: already shared the html code or check zulwadev.zulwa.com/zulwafront

Comment: so you want text box in one row and two buttons in second row?